# Blandford-Znajek process - energy flow reverse and other questions

Tags: magnetic-fields, kerr-metric, magnetohydrodynamics

In the original BZ paper [[1]](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/179/3/433/962905) from 1977, the authors invoke a number of facts and conclusions that I do not quite follow. In the hope that someone has read it and was able to grasp all the details, I am interested in the following:

1. At $\theta=\pi/2$, I can see why the toroidal component of the $B$ field, $B_{\phi}$ has a discontinuity due to the presence of a postulated radial current $J^{r}$, pointing in the opposite direction to the current which flows the field lines $A_{\phi}=\rm{const}$. Nonetheless, why is the $A_{\phi,\theta}$ derivative also postulated to have a discontinuity there? Is the $B_r \sim A_{\phi,\theta}$ discontinuous? How?
2. In eq. 4.11, why is the determinant of the full metric ($\sqrt{\det g_{\mu\nu}}$) used, instead of the determinant of the metric induced on a sphere at a sufficiently large radius (say, $\sqrt{\det \sigma_{AB}}$)?
3. Why is it claimed that the energy flux $\mathcal{E}^\mu$ does not change direction as long as the force-free conditions hold (claim to be found below eq. 4.4)? More specifically, what should I calculate to show that it is indeed the case?
4. It seems crucial to the argument that the boundary condition on $B_{T}$ at the horizon is used. However, later in the literature, Komissarov made arguments that point to the role of the (causally connected) ergosphere instead of an inaccessible mechanism inside the event horizon. What is the status of this mechanism as understood nowadays?

[[1]](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/179/3/433/962905) https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/179/3/433/962905